# Displaying homepage with Pubby / Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat6

Does anyone know how to go about displaying a custom homepage when Pubby is the root of Apache Tomcat?

My current setup is `\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\ROOT\` <- Pubby folders `WEB-INF` and `static` are in this folder.

Whilst creating custom pages for e.g. `localhost:8080/About` is completely fine, (I just create a folder within my webapps folder called "About", and put my index.html in there), I don't how to get a custom index.html to display when I navigate to `localhost:8080`

I've tried sticking index.html files across my directories, but `localhost:8080` won't resolve to any of them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index files for `http://localhost:8080/` will be defined in $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml with defaults taken from $CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml

Assuming the ROOT app does not specify any welcome pages then an index.html placed at $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/ROOT/index.html should do the trick.

Comment: The ROOT app doesn't specify any welcome pages, but the index.html file in that location still doesn't work, I get a 404 not found error with the Pubby header

Comment: Then Pubby must be overriding the default servlet. If that is the case there is nothing you can do unless Pubby provides an equivalent mechanism to welcome files.

Comment: I'm afraid that may be the case. Thanks for your help though!